# TypeError cannot read property 'reactScript' of undefined

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, axios, dom-events

I get callback method twice in Android when I make a call from axios in React Native,
My button JSX,

```
<BuddyButton onPress={this.callPostWebService.bind(this)}>
```

My event method on button pressed,

```
validateLogin = () => {
  ...
   WebserviceHelper.postValues(webServiceName, valuesJson, this);
 }
```

My Axios calling method

```
exports.postValues = function(webServiceName,valuesJson, callbackRef) {
  instance.post(webServiceName, valuesJson)
  .then(function (response) {
    alert(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    alert(error);
  });
};
```

Now in above code first i got success message and my response block got call and after within second error block called. And throwing me error:

> **TypeError cannot read property 'reactScript' of undefined**

In first time I get correct web response, and second time I get error message.
I'm using react-native version 0.34.1 and axios version 0.14.0.

Above code working fine in iOS simulator as well as device.